# Justify sub bullet points with bullet points

Tags: html, html-lists

**Solved!**
I set the margin to 0 (instead of 0 auto) and added a padding left for each individual li in my type="a" ordered list.

**Initial Question**
I have list of numbered bullet points with type a bullet points (e.g. a,b,c) like so:

**text.html**

```
<div class="content-section">
  <ol> 
    <li>this is a sample text that stretches across the page
       and it takes up the second line</li>
    <ol type="a"> 
      <li>this is a sample text that stretches across the page</li>
      <li>this is a sample text that stretches across the page</li>
      <li>this is a sample text that stretches across the page</li>
    </ol>
    <li>this is a sample text that stretches across the page
        and it takes up the second line</li>
    <ol type="a"> 
       <li>this is a sample text that stretches across the page</li>
       <li>this is a sample text that stretches across the page</li>
       <li>this is a sample text that stretches across the page</li>
     </ol>
   <ol>
<div>
```

**text.css**

```
.content-section {
  p,
  li {
    max-width: 900px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: $color-hint;
  }
}
```

What it looks like:

```
1) this is a sample text that stretches across the page
   and it takes up the second line
   a. this is a sample text that stretches across the page
   b. this is a sample text that stretches across the page
   c. this is a sample text that stretches across the page
2) this is a sample text that stretches across the page
   and it takes up the second line
   a. this is a sample text that stretches across the page
   b. this is a sample text that stretches across the page
   c. this is a sample text that stretches across the page
```

I'm trying to justify the content so that the sub bullet points cut off at the same point as the numbered bullet points so both sides of the content appear justified.

Any ideas on how I can do this? I tried adjusting the padding and margins but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I've updated my code!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with the HTML

```
<p>1) This is sample Text</p>
<ol type = "a" id = "bullet">
  <li>Sample Text</li>
  <li>Sample Text</li>
  <li>Sample Text</li>
</ol>
<p>2) This is sample text</p>
<ol type = "a" id = "bullet">
  <li>Sample Text</li>
  <li>Sample Text</li>
  <li>Sample Text</li>
</ol>
```

Then add this to CSS

```
#bullet{
left:10px;
}
```

Might not need the CSS tho as lists automatically indent

Comment: sorry about that maybe left-margin would work better?

Comment: it's okay, I found a solution! thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted ;)